# Symfony Doctrine Query returns Array instead of Object

Tags: sql, symfony, object, doctrine

I've found a lot of questions going the other way but none that explain why I'm getting an Array when I use inner joins.

My Query:

```
$entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();
$query = $entityManager->createQuery(
   'SELECT sp, p
    FROM App\Entity\Portal\StaticPage sp
    INNER JOIN sp.portal p
    WHERE p.id = :id
    AND sp.name = :name'
)->setParameters(array('name'=> $name, 'id'=> $id));

return $query->getOneOrNullResult();
```

This gives the following error: `Notice: Undefined index: staticpage`

But if I do this:
`return $query->getArrayResult();`

I get the following output:

```
array[
  0 => array [ Object in array form ]
]
```

Any ideas how to get the object instead of an array with all the values in?

Comment: You probably have a wrong or missing annotation in your Entities, try launching `doctrine:schema:validate` from your console to check everything is ok.

Comment: since getOneOrNullResult is supposed to return one object or null, I could Imagine that being the culprit here. does that `[ Object in array form ]` also include the portal? The error message is weird though ... have a look at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-result-formats specifically the paragraph after the list and hydration modes.